# Use Stokes' or Divergent Theorem?

Tags: surface-integrals

I don't know whether to apply Stokes' Theorem or the Divergent Thereom to this problem I've been given!

"Calculate $\iint_S \vec F.d\vec S$, where $\vec F=x(x-1)yz\hat i+e^xsin(\pi y)\hat j +x^2y^2z\hat k$ and $S$ is the surface of the unit cube $0\le x,y,z\le 1$"

I suspect it's the Divergent Theorem (it's a closed surface because it's a cube, right?), but any help getting me started would be much appreciated!

Comment: Divergence for sure :  step one : compute $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec F$

Comment: Try using the Divergence Theorem and see what happens.

Comment: My triple integral turned out to be (all with boundaries 0 to 1): ∫∫∫2xyz - yz + πe^xcos(πy) + x^2y^2 dx dy dz. But the answer I got seems wrong: π^2e^1 + 1/3 - π^2. Is there a problem with my setup or my integration skills?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\nabla \cdot \vec F=(2x-1)yz+\pi e^x\cos (\pi y)+x^2y^2$

So, your taking the Divergence is correct.

---

Next, we see that the first and second terms integrate to zero.

It appears that you have the first integral correct.

For the second integral, recall that

$$\left.\int \cos (\pi y)dy=\frac{\sin \pi y}{\pi}\right|_0^1=0$$

---

For the integral of the third term, we have

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1x^2y^2dxdydz=1\times \frac13\times \frac13 =\frac19$$

---

Putting it all together, we have that the integral over the cube is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1((2x-1)yz+\pi e^x\cos (\pi y)+x^2y^2)dxdydz=\frac19}$$